# Formatting time from Google Calendar API with Python

Tags: python, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to get an easy to read time format to list events from google calendar for the current day. I can pull in the data, but I'm having a problem formatting the data to be just the Hour and minute for both start time and end time.

I want to display the information in an easy to read list, so I want to drop the date and seconds and only display the time in order. I have tried several different methods including slicing and trying to convert into date time with no luck.

```
date  = datetime.datetime.now()
tomorrow = date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
yesterday = date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
now = str
data = '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(date)
tdata = '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(tomorrow)
ydata = '{:%Y-%m-%d}'.format(yesterday)
def DateQuery(calendar_service, start_date=data,  end_date=tdata):
  print 'Date query for events on Primary Calendar: %s to %s' % (start_date, end_date,)
  query = gdata.calendar.service.CalendarEventQuery('default', 'private', 'full')
  query.start_min = start_date
  query.start_max = end_date
  feed = calendar_service.CalendarQuery(query)
  for i, an_event in enumerate(feed.entry):
    print '\'%s\'' % (an_event.title.text)
    for a_when in an_event.when:
      dstime = (a_when.start_time,)
      detime = (a_when.end_time,)
      print '\t\tEnd time:     %s' % (dstime)
      print '\t\tEnd time:     %s' % (detime)
```

It prints like this

End time:     2013-03-23T04:00:00.000-05:00

and I would prefer it be

End time:     04:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the dateutil module:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse('2013-03-23T04:00:00.000-05:00')
>>> dt = dateutil.parser.parse('2013-03-23T04:00:00.000-05:00')
>>> dt.strftime('%I:%M')
'04:00'
```

If you don't want to use dateutil, you an also parse the string using the specific format with [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Comment: when I try  dateutil.parser.parse(dstime)
  dt = dateutil.parser.parse(dstime)    I get an error that says AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'read'. Any ideas

Comment: Got it!     for a_when in an_event.when:
            dstime = dateutil.parser.parse(a_when.start_time)
            detime = dateutil.parser.parse(a_when.end_time)
            print dstime.strftime('%I:%M')
            print detime.strftime('%I:%M')